# How can I access the running instance of IIS Express in my Windows Virtual Machine through my Mac OS?

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtual-machine, visual-studio

I'm a full stack android developer. I use android studio on my Macbook pro to develop apps and previously used visual studio on my windows VM to develop backend solutions and API's. This windows virtual machine is installed onto my Macbook.

When I run my solution using IIS Express to test API's on my virtual machine, is there any way to access the running instance of IIS Express in my virtual machine through my Mac OS? As in, can I consume the API's I'm running locally in the virtual machine, through let us say postman or an Android emulator, in my Mac OS?

I'd prefer to keep Android Studio in the Mac OS segment of my machine because it performs very well, just runs incredibly smoothly. I'd like to take advantage of that if possible instead of having to install it in the virtual machine. On the other hand, I need access to Microsoft SQL Server Manager, hence the virtual machine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?